# What is the best way to empty a Vector or Array in AS3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

What is the most efficient way to empty an Array or Vector in ActionScript 3?

I've always just re-initialized them:

```
vector = new Vector.<T>();
array = [];
```

It doesn't look like there's an `empty()` function or anything similar.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Re-initializing the array is fine in most cases, since the garbage collector will just sweep up the old array. Still, if you want to empty an array without creating a new one you can set `array.length = 0`

Comment: It does seem like it ought to be, but here we are.

Comment: @Marty Wallace that's because it is, I'm going into flashdevelop right now and setting `array.length = 0;` which will give me an error when I run it, here I go...right then...well I'll be damned O_O

Comment: Seems a tad flawed.. Haha, ohwell, great info.

Comment: The [adobe documenation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#length) on truncating an array by setting the length

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use the splice method.

[Array::splice documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29)

For an array the following call empties it:

```
array.splice(0);
```

For a vector the second parameter is enforced, so the call becomes:

```
vector.splice(0, vector.length);
```